# Fairness problem

Tags: probability, fair-division

I need to figure it out how  without exceeding the use of the number 10, find three different ways of distributing some blue and red marbles in a container, so that the probability of randomly choosing two marbles of the same color will equal that of different colors.
Someone can help?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If you have $r$ red and $b$ blue marbles, there are $\binom{r}2+\binom{b}2$ ways to choose two marbles of the same color, and $br$ ways to choose two marbles of different colors. Use this to write down an equation involving $r$ and $b$, and rearrange it to express $r+b$ in terms of $r-b$. Three small solutions are then quite easy to find by inspection (or a little very easy trial and error).

Comment: Great I will try it, Thanks!

Comment: I am stuck, at (r-b)^2 = r+b

Comment: @TAQ: $r+b$ has to be a square, and you want $r$ and $b$ to be small, so try letting $r+b$ be a small square. Clearly you need at least one marble of each color, so $r+b$ can’t be $1$; can you find solutions with $r+b=4$ and $r+b=9$?